# Delete specific files, exclude specific directories, batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory, delete-file

How do I search multiple folders from and the levels below where I'm running the batch file from and delete a file named for example "file Setup.msi" but Exclude the directory "%~dp0Installer-Upgrader". I have tried this:

```
FOR /r /d %%I in (CabiBond Setup.msi) do (
    if /i NOT "%%~nxI" equ "Installer-Upgrader" rmdir /q /s "%%~I"
)
DEL /q "file Setup.msi"

PAUSE
```

But from this same script I get message like:

> C:\Folder1\Folder2\setup.msi
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

And

> Could not find C:\Folder1\file Setup.msi

(C:\Folder1\ is where I'm running the batch file)

Unfortunately the msi (or exe with other file names I'm also going to add once this works) already has a space in it and this script will be run of hundreds of sites tiding up their install sets so the folder1 and folder2 or possibly more will all be randomly named and the folder I want to exclude will the the main master install set so can't touch this one but will be located among the others

Answer (score 0):

This shows the principal. You don't need first statement. Use dir and findstr. You can also use `for` loops.

To see size of folders in Documents, excluding music, video, or pictures folders.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"^|findstr /l /v "Pictures Music Video"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```